# Blank and white page Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have a problem with the page builder Elementor in WordPress.

All pages work but only one has an error like this:

[Screenshot of the error on the browser..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxglW.png)

I tried a lot of tricks like:
https://docs.elementor.com/article/362-erremptyresponse-while-editing-with-elementor

But it doesn't work.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: That looks like a 500 error. Do you have any php in the page builder?

Comment: No I didn't edit the page builder and I update all the plugins.